# PHP - How do you select a specific index of a row given by mysqli_fetch_array()?

Tags: php

Please refer to the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hBPC.png

*For instance, if a user clicks the button on the row  which says "You have a quiz for math", the "Quiz ID" value of THAT row would then be passed to another PHP file.*

Here's my current code:

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "quizmaker");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "MySqli Error: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
        }

    $now=date("m/d/Y"); 
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM quiz_query WHERE quiz_date='$now'");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    if($count>=1)
    {
    echo "<table border='1' width='50%'>";
    echo "<form action='answer_quiz.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<tr>
    <td>You have a pending quiz!</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>";
    $number=1;

    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>You have a quiz for " . $result['subject'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>Quiz ID: " .$result['quiz_ID']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='button' id='button' value='Take Quiz'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='quiz[$number]' value='$result[quiz_ID]'>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $number++;
        }


    echo "</form>"; 
    echo "</table>";    
    }
    else
    {
        "You have no quiz! :D";
        }

    mysqli_close($con); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you provide some more information on what you are looking for?  Are you running into an error?  You don't list a clear issue with your above code.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, but the issue has been resolved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this line:

```
echo "<form action='answer_quiz.php' method='post'>";
```

Inside of the `while` loop.

---

Also, change

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='quiz[$number]' value='$result[quiz_ID]'>"
```

with

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='quizId' value='$result[quiz_ID]'>"
```

Now, in `answer_quiz.php` you'll receive `$_POST['quizId']` with the value you need.

Comment: Damnit, Saturnix. You were literally 5 seconds faster than me :D

Comment: I know that feeling bro! :(

Comment: Have this +1 anyway :)

Comment: No problem. Please make sure to pinpoint your issue more precisely next time and to include just the relevant portion of the code. SO is a q/a website, people tends to get annoyed to "wall-of-text" questions. Not to mention, "here's me code, please let it do this and that". You'll get much more concise, performant and precise answers and it will help you a lot in understanding the problem. 90% of the times I solve my issues while writing the question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Change your while to :

```
while( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

 echo  $row['subject'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting quotes around your variable:
Instead of

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='quiz[$number]' value='$result[quiz_ID]'>";
```

It should be

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='quiz[$number]' value='$result[\"quiz_ID\"]'>";
```